# Que signifie le premier dans cette phrase?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions

> L'historien établit que dans un cas déterminé (la
> Belgique) la dévaluation a déterminé le retour des capitaux,
> l'abaissement du taux de l'intérêt, la reconstitution de la marge
> bénéficiaire, etc. Il démontre que 1° aucun autre événement
> n'explique ces phénomènes ni dans Ie cadre national, ni dans
> l'économie mondiale (on ne les observe pas au même moment
> dans les autres pays du bloc-or, aucun autre antécédent n'en
> rend compte); 2° ces phénomènes sont liés à la cause par des
> relations intelligibles (le retour des capitaux s'explique paг
> l'intérêt des capitalistes) ; 3° le rapport causal se déduit de règles
> empiriques ou scientifiques : dans une constellation déterminée,
> la dévaluation produit telles conséquences, telle est la forme du jugement causal historique.
> Du même coup, nous revenons au schéma simple, que nous
> avons écarté plus haut : la consécution singulière rentre directement dans la relation générale. Mais en même temps ce schéma apparaît comme un cas particulier du schéma complexe. **Le premier** s'applique lorsque les conditions sont normales ou constantes.

Comment: Cette phrase provient du livre de Raymond Aron, Introduction à la philosophie de l'histoire, p229

Answer (score 2):

> Du même coup, nous **revenons** au **schéma simple**, que nous avons écarté plus haut : la consécution singulière rentre directement dans la relation générale. Mais en même temps **ce schéma** apparaît comme un cas particulier du *schéma complexe*. Le **premier** [...]

Le premier ici fait référence au **schéma simple**, puisque c'est le premier qu'il mentionne lorsqu'il change de sujet. L'utilisation de "premier, deuxième, etc." va toujours faire référence au dernier sujet mentionné, donc rien à voir avec l'énumération de ce que l'historien démontre plus haut. Par contraste, on utiliserait "ce dernier" pour faire référence au schéma complexe.